# upgrading to iOS 7 and Xcode 5 - having issues with UIAccelerator, UIStringDrawing and NSObject

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I updated my iPad to iOS 7, and discovered that the Enterprise app that I have been working on for over a year crashes. OK, no problem, I'll see where in Xcode it's crashing.

OK, Problem: I have to upgrade to Xcode 5 to debug iOS 7. OK, no problem, I'll upgrade to Xcode 5.

OK, Problem: The source code in Xcode 5 now shows 19 errors: One in NSObject.h, three in UIStringDrawing.h, and the rest in UIAccelerometer.h.

And, for a bonus, it adds one at the bottom, "Too many errors emitted, stopping now." Which is not all that comforting.

I've really scoured the internet for answers, but I must be using the wrong search terms because I am finding nothing that addresses this. Surely I am not the only one.

I have been developing iOS apps for almost two years now, I think, but I am still pretty stupid when it comes down to the nitty-gritty stuff. I usually just hit "Run" and hope it works. So far that has been a pretty effective strategy, but now I am stumped.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Except the obvious, being that I should have left everything well enough alone.

I will also have to update my previous app, because it has iOS 7 issues too, but it scares me to even think of it.

I appreciate any help anyone can give.

Comment: Was the version of the app that's crashing on your iPad built using the iOS 6 SDK or the iOS 7 SDK? If you build using the iOS 6 SDK and get that version of the app onto your iOS 7 device (the only way I currently know how to do this is via TestFlight - Xcode 4 won't push stuff to iOS 7 devices and after a fair bit of effort I couldn't get Xcode 5 to build with the iOS 6 SDK when running on iOS 6 devices or simulators) then the app should run in iOS 6 compatability mode and behave pretty much like it would on an iOS 6 device. If you're building with Xcode 5, though, the behaviour changes.

Comment: Basically, if you've only witnessed your crash when building with Xcode 5, then you may have nothing to worry about at all.

Comment: This app is being developed only for our field crews using iPhone, not necessarily for the iPad. Since I did not update my iPhone to iOS 7, I managed to remove Xcode 5 and reinstall 4.6.whatever, so now I am back to work on the app pre-xcode 5 / iOS 7.  However, sooner or later I'll have to move to iOS 7 and Xcode 5, so at some point will have to face this situation again. I'm hoping it will be resolved by then.  Thanks Mark, for the encouragement.  It appears that the two downvotes were canceled out by two up votes... assuming that's how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2013/09/how-to-support-old-ios-sdks-in-xcode-5/#comment-1056917662

After figuring out how to do all this, the app showed a couple more errors unrelated to the original problem. Turns out I had a couple of XIBs set for Autolayout. Those being disabled, the app worked great on my iOS 6 phone with Xcode 5.

Comment: @Shady, yes, it works fine on iOS 7. The only changes I needed to make were to update the UIButtons so they looked like buttons. That required having to create a button image and attaching it as the button's background image. The non-button buttons were too ambiguous; they needed to look like buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you were able to switch back to the iOS 6 SDK.  I had the same errors in `UIAccelerometer.h` and `NSObject.h`, but wanted to stick with the iOS 7 SDK.

For me, these errors were the result of stray copies of `UIKit.framework`, `Foundation.framework` (And a couple of other frameworks) inside my project folder.  These were seen by the linker, hence the "duplicate symbol" error messages thrown.  As soon as I got rid of the frameworks in the project folder and re-linked to the frameworks in "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary With Libraries," everything built.

Comment: I followed your lead and deleted and relinked the UIKit.framework and the Foundation.Framework. Doing so led me back to the original problem, where I had more than 19 errors. By chance I deleted the Foundation.framework without re-linking it, and it compiled just fine and is running normally on iOS7 with 64-bit architecture. I don't see anywhere in the project folder where there is another copy of the Foundation.framework, and it's not in the "Link Binary with Libraries" list. Yet the app is working fine. This is a little confusing for a greenhorn like me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are there any other "*.framework" files in the project folder?